# How to make a async loop wait 1 second between with iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an forEach loop that make an async call to an API:

```
array.forEach(async (item) => {
  await callAnApi(item)
})
```

I want to make this loop wait 1 second between the items - because the **API is getting sattured.**

**We need something like this:**

```
array.forEach((item) => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
     await callAnApi(item)
  },1000)
})
```

That way it doesn't work because the whole loop runs in the "same time" so every call will be fired "in the same time" after 1 second.

I already have searched for dozens of answers but none of them have solve this simple problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could increment the timeout delay:

```
array.forEach((item, count) => {
  setTimeout(() => callAnApi(item), count * 1000);
});
```

That sets up timers at 1 second intervals instead of all being at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]

const wait = (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, ms)
  )

const run = async () => {
  for (const a of array) {
    console.log(a)
    await wait(1000)
  }
}

run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```js
await array.reduce(
  (acc, item) => acc
    .then(() => callAnApi(item))
    .then(() => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))),
  Promise.resolve()
);
```

Note that this code will wait for an extra 1000ms after the final call is done, so you may want to improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the exact requirements, but since you know the length of the array, why not simply adjust the delay for setTimeout by the current index?

```js
[1,2,3].forEach((element, index) => setTimeout(() => yourApiCall(element), index * 1000))
```